# Click Event on ImageButton not dispatched immediately

Tags: android

I'm having a weird problem, in my rather complex view layout. (I will try to simplify it a bit  in my explanation)

Basically I have a `ListView`, where each item consists of a `TextView` and an `ImageButton`. I am able to either click the list item (on the textview), or the button (I set the ImageButton to non-focusable, otherwise it wouldn't work)

Now it seems to work fine, **until I open another window** and return to the listview.
From that point on, I can click the ImageButton without anything happening (not even the background changes during the click). But when I click on the TextView again, all the click events from the ImageButton are dispatched at once.

Why is that?

EDIT:

The List Item:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="0px"
    android:minHeight="40dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingLeft="2px"
    android:paddingRight="2px"
    >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Text"
        android:textSize="19dp"
        android:paddingTop="4px"
        android:paddingBottom="4px"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"/>

    <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/open_subtree_layout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="0px"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="0px">

        <View
            android:layout_width="1px"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/separator_line" />

        <com.treeviewer.leveldisplay.DontPressWithParentImageButton
            android:id="@+id/btn_right"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:background="@drawable/list_selector_background"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:src="@drawable/arrow_right" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

That's how it is inflated:

```
    [...]
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
mView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tree_row, null, false);

TextView textView = (TextView)mView.findViewById(R.id.text1);
LinearLayout nextNodeButtonContainer = (LinearLayout)mView.findViewById(R.id.open_subtree_layout);

if(childCount >= 0) {
    titleBuilder.append(" (" + childCount + ")");
    nextNodeButtonContainer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    View button = nextNodeButtonContainer.findViewById(R.id.btn_right);
    button.setFocusable(false);
    button.setFocusableInTouchMode(false);
    //button.setClickable(true);
    button.setOnClickListener(clickListener);

    button.setTag(tagValue);
} else {
    nextNodeButtonContainer.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}

textView.setText(titleBuilder);
```

Let me know, if you need more code.

Comment: Help us by posting some of that code here...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I finally solved this problem.

Unfortunately, in my question I didn't provide the necessary information to solve it, as the problem was somewhere I didn't expect it:

I have a `ListAdapter` where the getView method looks like this:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    return mNodes.get(position).getView(mNodeArrowClickListener, position);
}
```

And the `getView` method of the nodes (`TreeLevelElement`s) looked like:

```
public class TreeLevelElement {
    private final Context mContext;
    private View mView = null;

    //[...] other methods

     View getView(OnClickListener clickListener, final int tagValue) {
        if(mView == null) {
            //[...] produce a new View from XML
        }
        return mView;
    }
}
```

The problem was, that I stored the Views in my elements, so I guess that conflicted somehow with android strategy to reuse old views for new items.
I don't know what exactly happened, but now that I removed `mView` and create a new one every time, it works.

I will also change it to reuse the `convertView` instead.